# What is the difference between rejson.so and librejson.so?

Tags: redis, redisjson

I'm trying to setup RedisJSON on Redis Server with Ubuntu 20.04

and i built it using these steps from the docs (https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/#build-on-ubuntu-2004):

*git clone --recursive https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON.git 

cd RedisJSON 

./sbin/setup 

make build*

after the *make build* command, i have now 2 .so files: librejson.so and rejson.so

what is the difference between librejson and rejson? which one should i load as a module in the redis config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real different you can use them both.
rejson.so is just a rename of librejson.so